# Sonar: Possible nullpointer?

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception, sonarqube

I don't know why Sonar thinks that in the following line a NullPointer Exception may occur:

```
if (file == null || file.listFiles() == null || file.listFiles().length == 0) {//etc}
```

Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: Just because one invocation of `file.listFiles()` returns non-`null` does not mean the next one necessarily will do.  `file.listFiles().length` is therefore always an NPE risk.

Comment: Maybe the `NullPointerException` occurs *inside* the call to `listFiles()`? Or `listFiles()` returns something non-null at first, but `null` at the second call?

Comment: Besides the result of `listFiles()` changing: Is `file` visible to other threads (IOW: is it a field or just a local variable)? They can set it to `null` after the first invocation.

Comment: Would you be able to precise which rule is raising this issue (ie: rule key). Just to be 100% sure we are talking about a sonarQube rule and not a findbugs rule.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Expanding on my comment:

Just because one invocation of `file.listFiles()` returns non-null does not mean the next one necessarily will do.  You cannot in general rely on two invocations of the same method (on the same object, with the same arguments) to return the same value, and any method returning a value of reference type may, in principle, return `null`.  On reflection you will recognize that you often depend getting different results for different invocations of the same method.  `file.listFiles().length` is therefore always an NPE risk.

Even if you expect Sonar to have specific knowledge of the `File` class (which does not necessarily seem reasonable), it is genuinely possible for evaluation of your compound conditional expression to throw an NPE.  All that needs to happen is for the referenced file to be removed between evaluation of `file.listFiles()` and evaluation of `file.listFiles().length`.

You could correct this particular issue like this:

```
File[] files;
if (file == null || (files = file.listFiles()) == null || files.length == 0) { /* ... */ }
```

Of course, as @zapi said, if `file` is modifiable and accessible to other threads, then pretty much all bets are off.

Comment: is it possible to declare a final variable with similar syntax? currently `File[] files` is not a final variable

Comment: @firstpostcommenter, if `files` is declared `final` then it must be initialized in its declaration with the value you want it to have.  That can be accommodated to reach an equivalent result, but it does not afford a value being assigned to `files` inside the `if` condition.